# SOLR JSON data in MySQL DB column

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

We have a MySQL table with below columns and sample data

```
|ID | Properties
|12 | {"ownerfirstname":"abc","ownerlastname":pqr","coownerfirstname":"xyz","coownerlastname":"piu",.......}
|13 | {"ownerfirstname":"fdhjfh","ownerlastname":fdhfjh","coownerfirstname":"","coownerlastname":"",.......}
|14 | {"ownerfirstname":"qew","ownerlastname":fdfjh","coownerfirstname":"egwh","coownerlastname":"ewew",.......}
```

Our application can search on ID or partial text on owner or co-owner firstname and lastname. I am planning to use SOLR - DataImportHandler to load/index data from MySQL.

> SOLR fields { "ID":"" "ownerfirsname":"" "ownerlastname":""
>   "coownerfirstname":"" "coownerlastname":"" }

For this to work, I need to parse the JSON in MySQL DB column and load as individual fields in SOLR to index while performing Full/Delta imports.

Is there any way I can do this with SOLR config or do I need to write custom coding to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question. I have used SOLR ScriptTransformer to write a Javascript to inspect the retrieved row from DB, build JSON object and get required fields.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer